# Adding nodes to MAAS

Tags: maas

**EDIT: The wiki page has been updated with the info. This has been resolved**
**Updated link : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/AvahiBoot?action=recall&rev=2**

I've been trying to add a node to my new MAAS server for quite a bit of time now. I installed MAAS on the master node using the Ubuntu Server install disk, then booted that same disk on one of my nodes, and chose my MAAS server when it came up in the install. The computer shut down, and it's name appeared in the main MAAS control panel (192.168.0.22/MAAS). I clicked on the node name, and clicked on "Accept & Commission". A blue message box poped up, and said

> Node Commissioning Started - You can boot this node using Avahi-enabled boot media or an adequately configured dhcp server. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/AvahiBoot for instructions.".

That link, which is supposed to help me, just gives me a wiki page saying

> "**This page does not exist yet. You can create a new empty page, or use one of the page templates.**".

So what am I supposed to do next?

I have searched up AvahiBoot on Google, but it just gave me people who were getting error reports after using this Avahi. I have looked around askubuntu.com, but I didn't find anything that gave me an answer.

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.10 Quantal Quetzal.

EDIT: Also, on the main MAAS page, it tells me that there is 1 node in the cluster, but that it is offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the exact same thing. I also found that not many people here operate in mixed environments as I could find no information about getting MAAS to boot from PXE when using a Windows DHCP server. Having that link be broken and not fixed since December 20th is extremely frustrating for those of us who rely on the docs pointing to AVAHIBOOT.

Anyway, beyond the rant. Here is the link I used to access the old page. Hope it helps you!

-James

Edit: The actual link:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/AvahiBoot?action=recall&rev=2

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took almost a year to mark your answer as best :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this as same way but I ran into these errors as you come up with. The only solution I found is that if you can make your MAAS server as DHCP server or if this is not possible  manually set up the "next-server IP" to your "MAAS Server IP" and filename to "pxelinux.0" and run `autoboot` in PXE command line. It helped me and now my server and nodes are running.